# jQuery.post() inside a jQuery.post()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post, load

Imagine a website where the content is loaded via a menu with using jQuery .post() (or .get()).

Imagine that inside this dynamic loaded content should be another jQuery post to show some more things under the content

(all without navigating to a new file in the address bar)

Here is what i mean (but only the base frame...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="n" id="n" placeholder="Search..." />
<button id="click1">Go</button>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<br />
<div id="result" name="result"></div>

<script>
window.onload = (function(){
    /* attach a submit handler to the button */

    $("#click1").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'n: term',
              success: function(msg) {
                $( "#result" ).empty().append( msg );
              }
         });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, stop laughing, I know that the page only loads itself in the div and this is not working because of the same IDs... it´s [not Inception here](http://www.funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/659049/Xzibit+Inception/) ;-)

But even if I link a completely new page to it with new IDs it is not working...

Is it possible to add a new jQuery AJAX inside an existing, already with jQuery AJAX loaded content?

I think yes, but I can´t find my mistake...

/EDIT

I think I need to give a bit more input:

test.php

```
<input type="text" name="n" id="n" placeholder="Search..." />
<button id="click1">Go</button>
<div id="result" name="result"></div>

<script>
window.onload = (function(){        
    $("#click1").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'n: term',
              success: function(msg) {
                $( "#result" ).empty().append( msg );
              }
         });
    }); 
    $("#click2").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test3.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'n2: term',
              success: function(msg) {
                $( "#result2" ).empty().append( msg );
              }
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

test2.php

```
<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2" placeholder="Search..." />
<button id="click2">Go</button>
<div id="result2" name="result2"></div>
```

test3.php

```
<?php
echo 'It´s working!';
?>
```

My final question: Why is it not working? Why does it not output "It´s working!" at the end?

Comment: have you checked in the firebug that your ajax call actually gets a response?

Comment: yes, it seems that the second event never pushes... (click2), which is loaded with the first jQuery post...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put another post inside the success handler of the first post:

```
$("#click1").click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'n: term',
          success: function(msg) {
            $( "#result" ).empty().append( msg );

            $.ajax({/* params here */});
          }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When `$("#click2").click(..);` runs, the `#click2` element does not exist, so it doesn't work.

You can either move `$("#click2").click(..);` to inside the `success` handler for the first request, or you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: Perfect, thats it!!! Thanks a lot! And thank for the inception link ;-) (and Darcy, you were also right, but I was a bit stupid to not see this immediately... sry :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the use of `window.onload` in the AJAX response.  `window.onload` has already fired for the window.  You are not loading a new window so this will not fire.  Try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: Looking at your example further, if you're saying that original file you showed loads `test`, then you have a problem of duplicate IDs for `click1` and the problem with `click2` is that it doesn't exist at the time `click` is called.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i have understood you need to use `live` with the dynamically added elements like

```
$("#click2").live("click",function(){

//do ajax here

});
```

or you can use `delegate`

```
$("#result").delegate("#click2","click",function(){

// do the ajax here

});
```

[**`jquery live`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[**`jquery delegate`**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)